# How to List all Combinations of N Indices that Equal X

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, sum

I am trying to return an array with the following rules:
1. All unique combinations that sum to X
2. Each number is assigned a letter
3. Each letter can only be used once in a sum

```
// Cartesian join
function cartesian() {
  let r = []
  let arg = arguments
  let max = arg.length-1

  function helper(arr, i) {
    for (let j=0, l=arg[i].length; j<l; j++) {
      let a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
      a.push(arg[i][j]);
      if (i==max)
        r.push(a);
      else
        helper(a, i+1);
    }
  }
  helper([], 0);
  return r;
}

let a = ['A','B','C'];
let a1 = ['1','2','3'];

let arrays = cartesian(a, a1)

for(let i=1; i<arrays.length; i++) {
  file[i] = arrays[i].join('').toString();
}
```

The cartesian join will output [A1, B1, C1, A2, B2...]

How do I then add up combinations of N indices that have a sum of X, while only using a number once from each letter index?

Where N is number of letters that apply to sum.
Where X is sum total.

For instance if N = 3 and X = 5,

Output would be {A1, B1, C3}, {A1, B2, C2}, {A1, B3, C1}, {B2, C3}, {B3, C2}, etc...

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you can use any number up to 3 times, so I would start with an array

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

and then find all combinations that sum to 5, while using at most 3 entries and only using each entry once.

After finding the numbers, then you can assign the letters. For example, the numbers `1,1,3` can be expressed as `A1,B1,C3`, `A1,B3,C1` and `A3,B1,C1`. If you had three different numbers, there would be six ways to assign the letters.

In short, find the numerical solutions first, and then assign the letters.